# How can I find applications that currently use the portable hard disk I have attached

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, command-line

When I try to safely remove my portable disk, most of the time I get a message that the device is currently being used by some application(s).

To solve this issue, I close all the open windows and related applications to remove the portable disk. My problem is that sometimes this approach does not work.

Is there a solution to this or can I search from the command line which applications are currently using the portable hard disk?

Comment: The disk activity tab of resource monitor would show you this. I'm not aware of a cli equivilent of this. At the very least it tells you *what* is using the disk

Comment: @JourneymanGeek At least in my case it will still only list activity. So in case some file is still opened, but nothing happening, you won't see it there.

Answer (score 1):

When running into such issues, I'm typically using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)'s "Find Handle or DLL" accessible through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. It's no command line tool, but at the same time I don't think you'd like to force close everything using some batch file anyway?

Just enter part of the path that's obviously locked and it will try to list you all existing handles and loaded files having this in their path:

[image: Process Explorer Search]